# Replace comparing each cell with range comparing in Excel

Tags: excel

so I want to make a auto-increased number list using this:

```
=IF(OR(C9<>"",D9<>"",E9<>"",F9<>"",G9<>"",H9<>""),B8+1,"")
```

But entering each condition `CX<>"", DX<>""...` is too troublesome. Is there a way to find if any of the cell in range `CX` to `HX` (or better the whole row) is filled with value?

I tried `CX:HX<>""` but it doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: Please try `COUNTA(C9:H9)>0` as your condition.

Comment: Great, it works. If only you answered directly then I could up vote your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula to find if there is at least one nonempty cell in range `C9:H9`:

```
=COUNTA(C9:H9)>0
```

Final formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(C9:H9)>0,B8+1,"")
```